# AWS S3 Replication - One source bucket to multiple destination bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement of copying objects from one s3 bucket to multiple destination bucket.

1. From bucket A, copy all object to Bucket B (different region)
2. From bucket A, copy objects with only few prefixes to Bucket C (same region)

I saw that multiple S3 replication rules can be applied to only one destination bucket. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious about the second one. Is this in another account, or the same account? What I'm wondering about is why you'd bother to replicate it to the same region vs. just limit the access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated December 2020:** S3 Replication now supports replicating objects from one bucket to multiple destination buckets. See: [New – Amazon S3 Replication Adds Support for Multiple Destination Buckets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-replication-adds-support-for-multiple-destination-buckets/)

Comment: I was typing up an answer and going to suggest those 2 exact things but you beat me to the punch!

Comment: Actually discussed this topic today on the [AWS Certification Quiz Show](https://youtu.be/MdO4Ki4kTgw?t=1627).

Comment: Thanks John, I am taking the route of AWS S3 Sync command but with a Jenkins scheduled script, thereby eliminating need of separate EC2.